# Firebase crash is causing the following error in Android App

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following error on getting firebase reference from background service:

> Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to
>   setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of
>   FirebaseDatabase instance.
>                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zzhM(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.firstnotify.moveit.Activity.LoginActivity.initFirebase(LoginActivity.java:104)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.firstnotify.moveit.Activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:98)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Is it possible to update firebase realtime database from background service because in my app its working fine when I tried from activity but getting this particular error when tried from service

Comment: ,have you managed to find solution?